# Can I extend serviceNodePortRange in running kops cluster without restart

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I have the kops cluster running on AWS. I would like to extend the service node port range of that cluster without restart the cluster.
Is it possible? If yes, how can it be done?

Comment: Hi, you need to edit the value and restart the kube-apiserver http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2019/02/20/kubernetes-service-node-port-range

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it, but it does require a reboot of the control plane nodes (but not the woker nodes). This is due to the "immutable" nature of the kOps configuration.

To change the range, add this to your cluster spec:

```
    spec:
      kubeAPIServer:
        serviceNodePortRange: <range>
```

See [the cluster spec](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kops/pkg/apis/kops#KubeAPIServerConfig) for more information.

Keep ensure you do not conflict with [the ports kOps require](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/contributing/ports/)